# Accelerometer and Magnetometer sensor fusion to get Gyroscopic Data

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope, virtual-reality, magnetometer

I am making a raspberry pi robot with an FVP (First Person View) camera mounted on a Pan/tilt Servo. I want to make it VR compatible by connecting it to my Phone. But my phone doesn't have Gyroscope sensor to detect horizontal movements, but it has magnetometer and accelerometer. How can I combine data from accelerometer and magnetometer to make a virtual gyroscope that can move with my camera. I am noob in all of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an [rotation vector sensor that](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types.html#rotation_vector) is already fusing the two. You will not get better results than it.

Note that this will not be as high quality as a proper gyroscope and will have artifacts if the robot moves.

If you're still interested in how to make this yourself, you can get roll and pitch information from the accelerometer, then get the yaw information from the magnetometer. Best if you find a library for 3d maths and do this with quaternions or matrices. This seems like a use case where you will be affected by gimbal locks easily, so euler angles will be problematic.

I guess you want to use this for VR? Don't try to move the servos to compensate for head movement directly, you'll only make a motion sickness generator. Look at how timewarp works - you move the servos in the general direction a person is looking at and render the video reprojected on a sphere - this way you have almost zero lag.